# Category theory to Computer Programming | Do objects map to Types or instances of Types?

Tags: category-theory

The building blocks of Category theory are defined by `objects` and `arrows`.

If arrows can be seen as programming language's functions; do objects map to Types; or an instance of a Type ... or "either" or "both" or it doesn't matter or ...?

I've seen the unit arrow described in Programming terms as both

a.) a function that returns the same instance it gets passed in; but with Generics / Templates

func  identity (a: A): A { return a; }

b.) and also as "add zero" for the category of addition

func sum (i: Int): Int { return i + 0; }

I think it does matter because the number of objects in a category tends to be a meaningful aspect. So if objects are seen as the kind of the type (Int) in the second example; then the addition category consists of a single object; but if objects are seen as each integer; then the addition category has infinite objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` is an object in the category of types and functions, and `sum` is a morphism from `Int` to `Int`.

`identity` is a polymorphic function, so it's a *family of morphisms* indexed by type. Such a family of morphisms is called a *natural transformation*. Its component at `Int` is the same morphism as your `sum`.

Comment: Dr Bartosz; the honor! I am; not that surprisingly reading your book :) Now I'm struggling with: `sum` is a `morphism.` Is`sum` modeled by many `morphisms` in the category of sets? One to represent " + 0" (the identity morphism) and another to represent "+ 1" which is not an identity morphism? Although; once in the category of sets - we not allowed to think of "+ ..." since objects don't have instances, so maybe we only think about two morphisms? But if we add in "multiplication" then do we distinguish between the "sum" identity morphism and the multiplication "identity"? (x 1) morphism?

Comment: When the book states "natural numbers with zero form a monoid under addition." Is that still with reference to the category of sets? Or is it with reference to a different category definition?

Comment: Functions between sets are just sets of pairs (argument, result). We can implement the same function in many different ways in a programming language, but if it's the same set of pairs, it's the same function, and the same morphism in Set.

Programmers are often confused about single-object category definition of a monoid, because in programming, in the category of types, a monoid is just one object of many. A better definition comes later, when you learn about monoidal categories.